# Thermostat is not starting furnace using Taco sr502

Tags: hvac, cooling, heat

I have a taco sr502 (2-zone switching relay). At the thermostat, there is no power when I hooked up a voltage meter to the red & white thermostat wires. No heat or ac is turning on. There is a green power light at Taco sr502 which indicates power at the switch.  The red zone 1 light does not turn on from the thermostat. Do you know what is wrong at the Taco sr502?

Also, I replaced the thermostat last spring. The old thermostat had a leaky battery. I was able to run the ac all summer. Have not run either heater or ac for the past 2 months.

Comment: did you check the battery

Comment: how about a picture

Comment: Since the AC works, it's reasonable to assume that your AC wiring connections are good. However, the heat doesn't work, so it's reasonable to assume that your heat connections are _not_ good. Double check all your wiring on the heating side of things, both at the thermostat and at the furnace (for good measure). It may be worth double checking the battery, just to be sure, since you haven't used the thermostat at all for 2 months, if it was on its last legs when you turned the AC off, it might be dead now.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the advice. I had a tech come over and it turns out the common at the thermostat was causing a short.  The common is not needed so it is now not connected and all is working.